Raspberry PI with a Waveshare UPS (D) and a PICAN-M hat
I have a RPI 4 that i'm using on my boat to run OpenCPN.
On it I have a WaveShare UPS (D) Hat with 2x 21700 batteries. The power connection to the Pi is via POGO pins connecting to the 40 pin header underneath the RPi.
Also, I have PICAN-M NMEA board for the marine networking features for OpenCPN.
The Raspberry Pi gets its power from the PICAN-M board via the 12 volts from the NMEA2000 cable. The PICAN-M has a 3 A power supply to supply the RPi also via the 40 pin header.
Is it safe to attach the WaveShare UPS (D) hat to RPi, and will it power the charging circuit for the batteries?

I'm not sure anyone here can answer that question definitively as it seems to hinge on how much current the UPS draws charging batteries (from an unknown/unstated) state of charge, AND how much current the RPi is using doing the processing it needs to do. I will say this definitively: I ran this Q by my friend "Simple Math", and he said he would never try it on his boat.
